# continuity of f probably with heine

Tags: limits, continuity

there is a debate and the professor isnt available.

True / False:

Given that $f$ is continuous, does it mean that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f \left( \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \right)$$

exists?

I think it does, because the if $f$ is continuous that means the limit of $f$ as $x$ approaches $0$ exists. and the mentioned limit is $0$ when $n$ approaches infinity (similar to heine definition).

edit: apparently a teaching assistant said that it is not necessarily true because n is natural and therefore discrete? your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

If $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then it is continuous at $x = 0$. Let $f(0) = y_0$. For any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x| < \delta \implies |f (x) - y_0| < \varepsilon$.

Now let's consider your limit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f ((-1)^n n^{-1})$$

Since $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, this is the limit *of a sequence* $a_n = f ((-1)^n n^{-1})$. We would expect this limit to be $y_0$. To show that this is indeed the case, let $\varepsilon > 0$ be arbitrary; we need to find $N \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $|a_n - y_0| < \varepsilon$ for each $n > N$. By continuity of $f$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that $|(-1)^n n^{-1}| = n^{-1} < \delta \implies |a_n - y_0| < \varepsilon$. Pick $N = \lfloor \delta^{-1} \rfloor$, and you are done.